# Preserving state in a conditionally rendered react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react app has a toggle button called Technical. If it is toggled on, we display , a custom component that offers a collection of highly technical options for the user. It has a lot of state. I am having this problem: when the user toggles the Technical button off, the stored state vanishes, and when the button is toggled back on, we are returned to the default state.

How can I preserve that state while making the FilterGroup (and the screen real estate it takes up) temporarily vanish?

Already tried:

1. Wrapping this entire item in <> </>
2. Wrapping FilterGroup in <> </>

Here's the relevant code:

```
{technical ? <FilterGroup ref={(fg) => theFilterGroup = fg} /> : null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a prop to `FilterGroup` to indicate whether or not to show it.

```
<FilterGroup show={technical} ref={(fg) => theFilterGroup = fg} />
```

```
const FilterGroup = forwardRef({show}, ref) {
    // hooks here...
    if (!show) return null;
    // return actual content...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Unmitigated, for half the answer. Here's what else I had to do. This is an excerpt from my FilterGroup render function, as corrected.

```
        {range.map((r, i) => (
          <div className="box">
            <div className="rc-slider" key={i}>
              <label className="common-label">{r.name}</label>
              <Range
                min={r.min}
                max={r.max}
                defaultValue={[this.state[r.from], this.state[r.to]]}
                handle={this.handle}
                tipFormatter={(value) => `${value}`}
                onChange={(e) => this.rangeChange(e, r.from, r.to)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

By way of explanation, **r.from** and **r.to** (fields of each Range object in the range array) are strings which are field names in **this.state**.  **r.min** and **r.max** are numbers. Previously the defaultValue line read:

```
                defaultValue={[r.min, r.max]}
```

and this default value was being reimposed every time the FilterGroup reappeared after having disappeared.